# MySQL Intersect on same table

Tags: mysql, intersect

My original query is:

```
SELECT * from test where ID BETWEEN 10 AND 100
INTERSECT
SELECT * from test where MARKS=10
```

But, `INTERSECT` is not working in MySQL
I am querying from the same table and `INNER JOIN` is not working.

Comment: What "not working" means? Why not just use `AND` for predicates?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work fine.

```
SELECT * from test where ID BETWEEN 10 AND 100
INTERSECT
SELECT * from test where MARKS=10
```

However you can verify it against this, which is a better way to do the same thing.

```
SELECT * from test where ID BETWEEN 10 AND 100
                     and  MARKS=10
```

If the both give you the same then they are both working and there is something about your data you don't understand.